# How to verify all four variants of the URL to Google Search Console for Shopify?

Tags: google, url, search

How to verify all four variants of the URL to Google Search Console for Shopify?

I have a main variant with www. It's conected with the Analitycs (this one shows the data), but Google Search Console doesnt show any search reports. So was thinking to add all the 4 variants, but i have no idea how to verify, because the verification via Analytics doesnt work and this is a shop on Shopify.

Comment: Did you try the guide from shopify? https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/store/verify-domain-with-third-party-services

Comment: Yes, I used it for the first verification. But now i have a problem how to verify rest of the variants.

Comment: What do you mean by variants?  Are they subdomains?

Comment: @ankDasCo  I assume they mean `http://example.com` `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com`, and `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Do all the other variants redirect to your preferred variant?  If so the meta tag in your preferred variant as suggested by Shopify is enough to verify all four.